# How to store output of Sqoop list-tables command to text file?

Tags: sqoop

Sqoop list-tables command display the list of tables from particular database to console. I want to store that output in to text file. Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Redirect your sqoop command output to a file. Below is the sample Sqoop command to redirect to a file

```
sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/learning --username root --password-file "/Learning/sqoop/.password" > tables
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Uva, Thank you for reply. Solution provided by you worked for me

Comment: Welcome Kartiki. Can you please upvote and mark this as answer?